# Concat in xslt, unable to get an image from server

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt coding, I am trying to fix an issue in existing piece of code. I got stuck up at a point

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="150pt" 
  content-height="50pt" 
  src="url:{concat('${OA_MEDIA}/',$revised_last_name,',',DOCUMENT_BUYER_FIRST_NAME,'.gif')}" />
```

The above piece of code is trying to find a .gif file in OA_MEDIA directory. Till that part I can understand fine.

When I am placing a file name as "Eckert,Tim.gif" (excluding the quotes) my program isn't picking that file

In the above piece, I printed $revised_lastname and $document_buyer_first_name..It's coming as Tim and Eckert, but it's still not picking the file. If I am hardcoding a file name like below it's working fine

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="150pt" 
  content-height="50pt" 
  src="url:{concat('${OA_MEDIA}/','Tim','.gif')}" />
```

How can I print what value is coming into the **src** in above piece of code so I can see what file is it trying to look in the $OA_MEDIA.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem appears to be that in your constructed URI and your file name, you have put the given name and the family name in different orders:  Tim,Eckert.gif vs Eckert,Tim.gif.  Choose one.

If you still have problems after that, your next step is to confirm that your concatenation is producing the value you expect.  I'd add a line like

```
<xsl:message>Generating fo:external graphic with URI <xsl:value-of
  select="concat('url:', 
                 '${OA_MEDIA}/',
                 $revised_last_name,
                 ',',
                 DOCUMENT_BUYER_FIRST_NAME,
                 '.gif')"/></xsl:message>
```

And if that did not shed light on what was going wrong, I'd insert individual messages to display the current value of `$revised_last_name` and `DOCUMENT_BUYER_FIRST_NAME`.

More than that it's difficult to say, because your question does not provide a short, self-contained, complete example that allows readers to reproduce the problem you are trying to solve.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: I fixed that file name but it still didn't help